# sklearn ImportError: cannot import name plot_roc_curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to plot a Receiver Operating Characteristics (ROC) curve with cross validation, following the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html) provided in sklearn's documentation. However, the following import gives an `ImportError`, in both `python2` and `python3`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name plot_roc_curve
```

`python-2.7` sklearn version: `0.20.2.`

`python-3.6` sklearn version: `0.21.3.`

I found that the following import works fine, but it's not quite the same as `plot_roc_curve`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
```

Is `plot_roc_curve` deprecated? Could somebody try the code and let me know the sklearn version if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotting API was introduced in the [version 0.22](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html#id5). As mentioned [here, Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Scikit-learn now requires Python 3.5 or newer.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)

Answer (score 14):

plot_roc_curve has been removed in version 1.2. From 1.2, use RocCurveDisplay instead:

Before sklearn 1.2:

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
svc_disp = plot_roc_curve(svc, X_test, y_test)
rfc_disp = plot_roc_curve(rfc, X_test, y_test, ax=svc_disp.ax_)
```

From sklearn 1.2:

```
from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
svc_disp = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(svc, X_test, y_test)
rfc_disp = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(rfc, X_test, y_test, ax=svc_disp.ax_)
```

Answer (score 8):

Install scikit-plot and import the metric from there:

```
from scikitplot.metrics import plot_roc_curve
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated `Conda` with `conda update --all` and then updated `scikit-learn` to the latest version which for me was `conda install scikit-learn=0.23.2` and restarted the kernel. After that my errors were gone.

Answer (score 1):

As the official sklearn's document mentioned: The function `plot_roc_curve` is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. If you would like more detail, please refer to [here](https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html).

Use one of the class methods: `sklearn.metric.RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions` or `sklearn.metric.RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator`. f you would like more detail, please refer to [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions).

Answer (score 0):

for

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_roc_curve' from 'sklearn.metrics'
```

use `RocCurveDisplay` instead of `plot_roc_curve`
as in `from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay`